# coredumpctl on Ubuntu 19

Tags: linux, ubuntu, core-dump

After updating my system to Ubuntu 19.04 I can't seem to find the `systemd coredumpctl` program. If anybody knows how to find it and/or some alternatives I would appreciate it. I use the program for debugging runtime errors with gdb.

Comment: FYI Ubuntu 19.04 is already EOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [the `systemd-coredump` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/disco/+package/systemd-coredump), *e.g.* by running

```
sudo apt install systemd-coredump
```

in a terminal.

Comment: oh thanks I was trying to install `systemd-coredumpctl`